# Second Derivatives Using Implicit Differentiation

Tags: calculus

According to my textbook, the second derivative of

\begin{equation*}
y^{2}+xy-x^{2}=9
\end{equation*}

is

\begin{equation*}
\frac{90}{(2y+x)^{3}}. 
\end{equation*}

The problem states "Express $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$." I've tried for two days straight now, and I can't get that answer. I am convinced the book has a typo.

Comment: What is the question? or what would you like to know?

Comment: muad: "express $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$", per the OP. In other words, what is $y^{\prime\prime}(x)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [your work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPD68.png) as linked in the comments on [J.M.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4920/second-derivatives-using-implicit-differentiation/4922#4922), you've very nearly got it (except for a typo in differentiating *: there's a dy/dx where there should be a d/dx, but the mathematics that follows is correct as if it were d/dx).  The numerator you have is 
$$\begin{align}
-2 ((2 x - y)^2 &+ (2 x - y) (2 y + x) - (2 y + x)^2)
\\\\
&=-10x^2+10xy+10y^2
\\\\
&=10(y^2+xy-x^2)
\\\\
&=10\cdot9
\\\\
&=90.
\end{align}$$

Comment: One little question: How did you get from the first step to the second step? When I factor it out, I get $2(5y^2+4xy-5x^2)$

Comment: I threw it into Mathematica and applied `Expand[]`.  Ignoring the -2 outside, the first item is $(2x-y)^2=4x^2-4xy+y^2$, the second is $(2x-y)(2y+x)=3xy-2y^2+2x^2$, and the third is $-(2y+x)^2=-4y^2-4xy-x^2$.  All together, $(4+2-1)x^2+(-4+3-4)xy+(1-2-4)y^2=5(x^2-xy-y^2)$.

Comment: I hate basic errors. Thanks Isaac!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: treat $y$ as a function $y(x)$, so differentiating $xy(x)$ should give something like $x y^{\prime}(x)+y(x)$. Differentiate expressions twice, and solve for $y^{\prime\prime}(x)$

Comment: I've tried that but I get a different result than the answer. I'll upload my work, just gimme an hour or so in LaTeX

Comment: Hmm, if you didn't get $\frac{10(y(x+y)-x^2)}{(2y+x)^3}$ ... something has gone horribly wrong.

Comment: Ok, so here's my work: http://imgur.com/4DDa7.png  I'm still not getting what's supposed to be the right answer.

Comment: M.: the numerator in your comment is $10(y(x+y)-x^2)=10(y^2+xy-x^2)=90$.